# How to escape comma in a CSV file, android

Tags: android, csv

I have a CSV file (the information is with Cyrillic letters, if matters). The CSV class is written so that it reads every row and splits it on a comma:

```
String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
```

In the csv I have rows in the following pattern:

```
ааа,бб, рр, ррр рр тт.
```

How can I force the CSV be split on the first comma only?
PS: I've already tried using double commas and blackslash in from of the comma, without any success so far.
EDIT:
Here is the whole CSVreader class:

```
public class CSVReader {
InputStream inputStream;

public CSVReader(InputStream is) {

    this.inputStream = is;
}

public List<String[]> read() {
    List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    
    try {
        String csvLine;
        while((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
            resultList.add(row);
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file:" + ex);
    } finally {
        try{
            inputStream.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: " + e);
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

}

What I need is the above excerpt from the CSV to be split on the first comma only, and the encountered after that to be parsed and shown on the screen.

Comment: can you link to the csv class ?

Comment: Can you please post your input and output. and also what is your expected output

Comment: Yes, the line is parsed and read. The problem is it forced to be split on the second comma as well.

Comment: I've added some more code, hope that helps

Comment: you could just call the split method after you have read all the lines instead of splitting it on each line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split only the first comma of each line, you can use

`csvLine.split(",",2);`

Where `2` is the `limit` parameter checking the maximum lenght of the resulting `String` array. This means that the split will only occur `limit-1` times. In your case, `1`.

As explained in JavaDocs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

With input `aa,bb,cc,dd` you'll get the array `{"aa","bb,cc,dd"}`